# openpyxl don't set the borders

Tags: python, openpyxl

[image: Text]
As you can see in the above image cells filled with color don't have the grid border. To restore the grid I use (found somewhere in stackoverflow):

```
def set_border(self, ws, cell_range):
        thin = Side(border_style="thin", color="000000")
        for row in ws[cell_range]:
            for cell in row:
                cell.border = Border(top=thin, left=thin, right=thin, bottom=thin)

set_border(self, sheet, "B6:AE4")
```

It don't work because `row` is empty. I tried similar codes, all of them fail when evaluating the range

Comment: ws[cell] cannot take a range of cells. 

You could use iter_rows, iter_cols
or you can also try using a regular for loop and set each cell value (border in your case) that way. eg. ws.cell(row=2, column=2).value = 5 (This sets cell B2 value to 5, change accordingly to set border insetad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting to set the border using Openpyxl you must set the border cell by cell so as @mrblue6 states you might use 'iter_rows' in you code to iterate each cell to set its border condition.

Firstly note that using another module like Xlwings will allow you to apply the borders across a range and may be the better method if you are using Windows with Excel installed.

This code example will set the thin border over the range 'B4:AE6' using Xlwings.

```
import xlwings as xw

xlfile = 'foo.xlsx'

with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    wb = xw.Book(xlfile)
    ws = wb.sheets['Sheet1']

    ws.range('B4:AE6').api.Borders.Weight = 1

    wb.save('foo_out.xlsx')
```

If xlwings is not suitable you can modify your code to set the border of the range as below;

**Note; You should use a forward range, i.e. in you description you have indicated a range "B6:AE4" which has the start row greater than the end row. The same range should entered as "B4:AE6" or an error will occur.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Border, Side
from openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range import CellRange

def set_border(ws, cell_range):
    thin = Side(border_style="thin", color="000000")

    rng = CellRange(cell_range)  # range to set borders
    for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=rng.min_row,
                            min_col=rng.min_col,
                            max_col=rng.max_col,
                            max_row=rng.max_row
                            ):
        for cell in row:
            cell.border = Border(top=thin, left=thin, right=thin, bottom=thin)


filename = 'foo.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(filename)
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

set_border(sheet, "B4:AE6")

wb.save('foo_out.xlsx')
```

Comment: t works, but to be honest the code in the question also works by changing, as you rightly suggest, the range values